# ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template :formats=>[:mobile]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In Rails, I'm trying to implement mobile views. Just installed `mobylette` gem which seems to be have more recent activity than mobile_fu.

https://github.com/tscolari/mobylette

However, most of the requests from the mobile device end up with this error

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template my_controller/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:mobile], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :haml]}. Searched in: * "/app/app/views" * "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.5.2/app/views" * "/app/app/views"
```

Any idea why?

Comment: what is your template file? could you give path relative to rails root please

Comment: I'm seeing this message when trying to create a new user with devise from mobile using default action `devise/registrations/create`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add the mobile format your self.

In config/initializers/mime_types.rb, add:

```
Mime::Type.register_alias "text/html", :mobile
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set the mime type and have `respond_to :mobile` in your controller, your only problem should be the mobile template file actually missing.

By default, you need to have a template file in the appropriate view_path called `<action>.<format>.<handler> or <action>.<handler>`

I suspect the default devise template (after successful create redirects to show action) is `show.html.erb`

your safest bet is to create it or symlink it (and all other actions)

```
ln -sf show.html.erb show.mobile.erb # in linux
```

Where? Well, if you used devise rake task

```
rails generate devise:views
```

then you know it'll be under `app/views/devise/registrations`

If you set `config.scoped_views = true` inside `config/initializers/devise.rb`, then it'll be under `app/views/users/registrations` given your devise model is User using UsersController.